# How can I make my Input text editable in react after getting data from databse

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I want to be able to edit my input text after getting my data from database. I fetch an initial value that is loaded to the input text, after that i want to be able to edit it but it is not working out.

```
 <InputText
                     value={props.loggedInEntity ? props.loggedInEntity.shortName: "not Loaded"}
                     editable={true}

                     onChange={(e) => setData({
                        ...data,
                        companyShortName: e.target.value
                    })}
                />

[So for example the text input loads the name of a company, i should be able to edit or update by selecting it ][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyvrq.png
```

Comment: What is InputText? Is this from some library? which?

Comment: This is prime react import {InputText} from "primereact/inputtext";

Answer (score 0):

You are passing *shortName* to value as a constant i.e prop. This is the reason it is not changeable/editable.

There are many workarounds for this. One of them is as follows:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { InputText } from "primereact/inputtext";


export default function () {
  const [shortname, setShortName] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    props.loggedInEntity
      ? setShortName(props.loggedInEntity.shortName)
      : setShortName("not Loaded");
  }, []);

  return (
    <InputText
      value={shortname}
      editable={true}
      onChange={(e) => {  
        setShortName(e.target.value); //changes the value in the editbox 
         setData({
      ...data,
      companyShortName: e.target.value,
    });
    }}
    />
  );
}
```